# os.openpty() Operation not permitted after os.seteuid() from root to a user

Tags: python, linux, pty

If we seteuid(123) from root to user 123, it will fail. However to run os.openpty() directly as user 123, it will be successful. Any hints?

Same in both python 2.7 or 3.6.  On Redhat 7:

```
>>> os.openpty()
(3, 4)
>>> os.seteuid(12345)
>>> os.openpty()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What happens if you just run it as root? (This is not a suggested fix, it's just a test to narrow down the possibilities.)

Comment: Also, you may want to port your example code to C and post it as a question with C, pty, and linux tags. Of course you shouldn't _have_ to do that to get an answer…but I suspect there's a higher chance of getting a quick and well-explained answer if you do.

Comment: If you have no idea how to do that, try [this](https://gist.github.com/abarnert/7ba70bacf10f922f95203998d2aac727), compiled with `gcc -o euidpty euidpty.c -lutil`. Of course haven't tested it, so it'll probably just segfault, but if you have even a passing familiarity with C and know how to `man openpty`, you should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: if I just run it as root, os.openpty() is good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `strace` output (best if using the C version):

```
setresuid(-1, 123, -1)                  = 0
open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR)               = 3
statfs("/dev/pts", {f_type=DEVPTS_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOSUID|ST_NOEXEC|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCGPTN, [6])                 = 0
stat("/dev/pts/6", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 6), ...}) = 0
getuid()                                = 0
chown("/dev/pts/6", 0, 5)               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
close(3)                                = 0
```

Since `geteuid()` is no longer root, it is impossible to change the TTY to be owned by `getuid()`.

Your choices are:

- change the UID, not just the EUID
- reset the EUID immediately before the `openpty` call, `chown` it yourself, then change the EUID again afterward
- implement `openpty` yourself ... on Linux it's pretty trivial (you don't need the awful BSD fallback) ... how portable do you need to be?

Comment: thanks for the answer! reset the EUID immediately means reset it back to root? 

we use pexpect and still needs to run a script as user 123 ( we start as root and set euid/egid to user 123 and needs to run a script as user 123) .

is this related to ulimit?

Comment: also why os.openpty() trigger a chown? was some TTY precreated by root even before I can os.openpty()??

Comment: For the former: Do you really need to keep any root privileges? For the latter: historical BSD-style TTYs were nasty, and we're still seeing traces.

Comment: Other possibilities: First, can you just call `openpty` right at the start, before `seteuid`? And, if you really need to preserve root ruid, and really need to be 123 euid before opening the pty, and really can’t temporarily switch back to root to do it, you could fork a child process to open the pty and hand the fds back—but this is way more complicated than you should need.